# Find the index of the row in data frame that contain one element in a string vector

Tags: r, dataframe, string-matching

If I have a data.frame like this

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(letters[1:4],"a"),col2 = 1:5,col3 = letters[10:14])
 df
   col1 col2 col3
1    a    1    j
2    b    2    k
3    c    3    l
4    d    4    m
5    a    5    n
```

I want to get the row indices that contains one of the element in `c("a", "k", "n")`; in this example, the result should be `1, 2, 5`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a large data frame and you wish to check all columns, try this

```
x <- c("a", "k", "n")

Reduce(union, lapply(x, function(a) which(rowSums(df == a) > 0)))
# [1] 1 5 2
```

and of course you can sort the end result.

Answer (score 0):

```
s <- c('a','k','n');
which(df$col1%in%s|df$col3%in%s);
## [1] 1 2 5
```

Here's another solution. This one works on the entire data.frame, and happens to capture the search strings as element names (you can get rid of those via `unname()`):

```
sapply(s,function(s) which(apply(df==s,1,any))[1]);
## a k n
## 1 2 5
```

Original second solution:

```
sort(unique(rep(1:nrow(df),ncol(df))[as.matrix(df)%in%s]));
## [1] 1 2 5
```

Comment: thank you very much, it is suitable for this example. However, if there are many columns in the data.frame, I am afraid this solution is not very convient.

Comment: I feel I must point out that your question said nothing about "many columns"; it stated "If I have a data.frame like this..." and then presented a three-column data.frame, only two columns of which are clear candidates for a letter search. My first solution is certainly the most straightforward and obvious one for such a task.

Comment: Thak you very much, it is really my fault. I should describe the question more clearly.

Comment: @ZihuGuo, see edit, I think my original second solution was incorrect. This is because I think you might want the result to be in order of `s`, IOW in order of the original search vector. My new second solution guarantees that. Is this correct?

Comment: Thank you very much for your patient. In fact, I do not want so much, I just want the row index regardless of the order. And I think the oringal second solution is more suitable, beacause there are multiple rows conatian `a`.